# One decorator for class and method

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-decorators

Is it possible to make one decorator which I could apply for classes and methods?

Example:

```
@my_dec(1)
class MyClass(object):
    @my_dec(2)
    def my_method(self):
        # something here

assert MyClass._x == 1
assert MyCLass.my_method._x == 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. Basically you need to create a function that accepts the value 1 or 2 and then returns the actual decorator to which the function or class object is later passed on, now inside the decorator we can use `setattr` to set the attribute on the class or function object.

```
def my_dec(x):
    # Here x is going to be the argument passed to my_dec, i.e 1 or 2 
    def decorator(func_or_cls):
        setattr(func_or_cls, '_x', x)
        return func_or_cls
    return decorator

@my_dec(1)
class MyClass(object):
    @my_dec(2)
    def my_method(self):
        pass

assert MyClass._x == 1
assert MyClass.my_method._x == 2
```

---

To understand how decorators work, do read this great answer: [How can I make a chain of function decorators in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/846892)

Comment: Thanx, it was too simply. :)